# Adding background color to the selected cell in Google sheets by script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

All,

I am trying to make a timestamp sheet. The idea is whenever a user will press a button the selected cell will get the current time and background color will change to RED. 
I managed to fix the time part but not able to get it change color. The closest I got to it is :

```
function timeStampM() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getActiveCell()
   .setValue(new Date());

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var actCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var actData = actCell.getValue();
var actRow = actCell.getRow();
if (actData != '' && actRow != 1)  //Leaving out empty and header rows
{
range.getRange(actRow, 2).setBackground('red');
}
}
```

This colors the cell in the 2 column of the selected cell rather than the cell itself. Any help will be hugely appreciated.

_Best Regards

Comment: It should be `sheet.getRange(actRow, 2).setBackground('red');` inside the if block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this appears to work:

```js
function timeStampM() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getActiveCell()
   .setValue(new Date());

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var actCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var actData = actCell.getValue();
var actRow = actCell.getRow();
if (actData != '' && actRow != 1)  //Leaving out empty and header rows
{
actCell.setBackground('Red');
}
}
```

Comment: I believe the question States that the code should change the background of column 2 of the selected row. Not the active cell itself.

Comment: Ahh, yes I missed that- I seen your answer above and have edited the above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, sorry if the question was confusing. I do aim to change the color of the selected cell and not the cell in 2nd column.

Comment: @OblongMedulla : Your old code worked like a charm. Thanks a billion, if you edit your code back to the old one, I'll mark it as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}